# Reactjs MobX observer re-render target

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, mobx

I'm new to react, and I've just started using state management tool Mobx. I am reading info about mobx here and there, but there are few concepts that I do not understand.

1. I know react re-renders every time if local state is altered using setState. It's re-rendering target is the component in which its local state has changed(am I right?). But for mobx, when the store's observable property has been changed by the action in an component, I'm not sure which component gets re-rendered here because this changed property is not 'local' as the example above.

   So for example, If I alter an observable property defined in class CityStore in a component called city(assume that I have other components as well), then which components will get re-rendered? does city component gets re-renders because I have altered the observable property there? or does all the components using that observable property gets re-rendered? I would like to know the mechanism of re-rendering of components with @observer decoration.
2. Created mobx store is passed on by using provider and @inject. I'm not quite sure what @inject does. If I wish to use store called cityStore in city component, I do follows:`<Provider city = {cityStore}> <city/> </Provider`>

   Then component city and all its child component can access and alter cityStore. then why do i have to seperately put @inject for every component that wishes to use cityStore if I have already used provider? is it just the syntax, so provider and @inject always has to go together? So for example, if I called `<Provider city = {cityStore}> <city/> </Provider>` on parent component city and do not put @inject for some child components of city component, that component will not be able to access cityStore?

Question description is a little long, but I will be really appreciated to know the answers thank you!

Comment: Read the documentation for mobx-react [here](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#observercomponentclass).